# How to flatten a chart and its pdf file using gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

After setting the size of the plot to smaller than the original size the pdf file generated is still on the same size. How do I make the plot and the pdf file smaller automatically?

```
set terminal pdf
#set pointintervalbox 0
set datafile separator ','
set size 1,0.75
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the size of the plot relative to your canvas.

```
set size 1,0.75
```

Check `help pdfcairo` and you will find that you set the canvas size, e.g. as follows:

```
set term pdfcairo  size 5.0in,4.0in
```